# Duplicating one element. of a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to duplicate just one element of a list.

```
list=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

So let's say I just want to duplicate the letter 'a'.
It would look like this:

```
list=['a','a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use insert:

```
list=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
list.insert(1,'a')
print(list)
```

1 : index where you want to insert the element

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.index()` to find out where the element is located and then `list.insert()` to insert it.

For example:

```
lst=['a','b','c','d','e','f']

def duplicate_element(lst, elem):
    lst.insert(lst.index(elem), elem)

duplicate_element(lst, 'a')
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```